# Android Communication through Modbus ASCII

Tags: android, ascii, modbus

Does anyone know any good tutorial on Modbus ASCII implementation. I have searched, but found out RTU and TCP one, not of ASCII

Answer (score 1):

I can't remind of a better explanation that the spec itself: http://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_over_serial_line_V1_02.pdf

Clause 2.5.2 details the encoding and framing.